# Objective C adding a tab bar item to change to other views

Tags: objective-c

I Have a normal view based application and have added an UITabBar component. I have found help how to create a tabbar app but nothing about how to use the UITabbar item separately

How may I use this to switch views please?

Comment: i suggest you to add the "iphone" tag to your question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you inserted your UIViewControllers in the UITabBarController?
You'd better [have a look at this guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW1) and maybe post some code of yours